# Post comment via Instagram Graph API returns 803

Tags: angular, facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I am developing an **Angular 6** app with **ngx-facebook** which should use the **Instagram Graph API** to publish comments on Instagram posts.

I went through the App Review process and acquired all necessary permissions *manage_pages, instagram_basic* and *instagram_manage_comments*.

I connected a Facebook page (where I am admin) to a Instagram Business Account. As an app user, I connected to Facebook via the Facebook Login and selected the Facebook page which is connected to the Instagram Business Account. On the Business Integration page on Facebook, I can see that the App is connected correctly to the Facebook page.

Now I want to post a comment via the Instagram Graph API and perform a POST request on /media/comments (via ngx-facebook) where I replace media with the platform id of the instagram post under which I want to post ('/1234567891011121314/comments?message=comment').

But the API returns:

```
{
    "error": {
        "message":"(#803) Some of the aliases you requested do not exist: 1234567891011121314",
        "type":"OAuthException",
        "code":803,
        "fbtrace_id":"<some-trace-id>"
    }
}
```

What could be possible issues here?

Comment: Issue fixed ? Can you post the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook Media ID which requested by the Graph API is a different ID than the Instagram Media ID.

E.g.

```
{
  "id": "17841405893765914",
  "ig_id": "1637486982933"
}
```